# Parameters passing in constructors - Java

Tags: java, swing, parameters, constructor

I have a `Person` class to describe some features of a person:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String birthPlace;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, String surname, String birthPlace, int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.birthPlace = birthPlace;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public String getBirthPlace() {
        return birthPlace;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

In `PersonDemo` class I create 4 people and I add them to an `ArrayList<Person>`. Then I pass the `ArrayList<Person>` to a `Frame` class (that extends `JFrame`):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PersonDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person p1 = new Person("Cristiano","Ronaldo","Santo Antonio", 31);
        Person p2 = new Person("Zlatan","Ibrahimovic","Malmo", 34);
        Person p3 = new Person("Alessandro","Del Piero", "Conegliano", 41);
        Person p4 = new Person("Zinedine","Zidane","Marseille",43);

        //ArrayList<Person>
        ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        people.add(p1);
        people.add(p2);
        people.add(p3);
        people.add(p4);

        //Create and make visible a new Frame() f passing 
        //as parameter the previous ArrayList<Person>
        Frame f = new Frame(people);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I split my frame with a `JSplitPane`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int X_AXIS = 175;
    private static final int Y_AXIS = 25;
    private static final int WIDTH= 930;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 600;

    private SplitPane splitPane;

    public Frame(ArrayList<Person> p) {

        this.setTitle("My Frame");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBounds(X_AXIS,Y_AXIS,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

        //pass to the splitPane the ArrayList<Person> p
        splitPane = new SplitPane(p);
        this.getContentPane().add(splitPane);   

    }
}
```

In the left side of `JSplitPane` I create a new `JPanel`; in this `JPanel` I have to work on the `ArrayList<Person>`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class SplitPane extends JSplitPane{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int SPLIT_WEIGHT  = 250;
    private JPanel leftPanel;

    public SplitPane(ArrayList<Person> p) {

        //pass to the JPanel leftPanel the ArrayList<Person> p
        leftPanel = new LeftPanel(p);
        this.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        this.setDividerLocation(SPLIT_WEIGHT);
        this.setLeftComponent(leftPanel);
    }
}
```

This is my `LeftPanel` class that extends `JPanel`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LeftPanel extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LeftPanel(ArrayList<Person> p) { 

        JLabel label = new JLabel("This is the left side of \"My Frame\"");
        this.add(label);

        //some code to work with ArrayList<Person> p in this JPanel 
    }
}
```

I wonder whether to pass the `ArrayList<Person>` in constructors (`JFrame -> JSplitPane -> JPanel`) is a good approach or there are better solutions (maybe inheritance).

Comment: That approach is totally fine; dependencies of one class are immediately clear when being passed by constructor. Inheritance makes no sense in this case. Alternatively, you may consider defining your GUI classes nested in one class, where you can directly access the `List<Person>` (in case you do not need to re-use those classes).

Comment: This type of question is better suited for CodeReview or Programmers. I suggest you *carefully read* their help center pages about asking and then format your question according to the one that better suits your question. You can ping me if you want another pair of eyes, then flag for a moderator for migration.

Answer (score 3):

A common strategy in implementing UI programs is to use [*Model-View-Controller*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html) approach. In your program, Swing classes would be the *view*, while `Person` and `ArrayList<Person>` would be the *model*.

Views need access to the data from the model in order to display relevant parts to end users. There are three common ways of giving views access to the relevant parts of the model:

- **Pass model parts in the constructor** - this is the approach that you took,
- **Make model a singleton** - this approach lets all views access all parts of the model,
- **Use inversion of control containers** - this is an advanced approach that lets you configure access in a declarative way.

The third approach is probably too advanced for the small program that you develop, but the singleton may work better than passing lists explicitly:

```
class Model {
    private static List<Person> people;
    public static List<Person> getPeople() {
        return people;
    }
    public static void setPeople(List<Person> people) {
        this.people = people;
    }
}
```

Now your `main` would do this:

```
Person p1 = new Person("Cristiano","Ronaldo","Santo Antonio", 31);
Person p2 = new Person("Zlatan","Ibrahimovic","Malmo", 34);
Person p3 = new Person("Alessandro","Del Piero", "Conegliano", 41);
Person p4 = new Person("Zinedine","Zidane","Marseille",43);

//ArrayList<Person>
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
people.add(p1);
people.add(p2);
people.add(p3);
people.add(p4);
Model.setPeople(people);
```

Your swing classes would no longer pass around `ArrayList<Person>`. Instead, they would do `Model.getPeople()` each time that they need to access `List<Person>`.